# Getting error in loading Configuration file,Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, configuration, installation, string-formatting, configurationmanager

I have an installer class which is retrieving the parameters from the Visual Studio Setup project.Now on opening the exeConfiguration i am getting following error..

```
Error 1001:An error occurred loading a configuration file.
The parameter 'exePath' is       invalid.
Parameter name:exepath-->The Parameter   'exePath'   is invalid.
Parameter name:exePath
```

And here is my Installer.cs Code..

```
public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
    {

        base.Install(stateSaver);

        string targetDirectory = Context.Parameters["targetdir"];

        string param1 = Context.Parameters["Param1"];

        string param2 = Context.Parameters["Param2"];

        string param3 = Context.Parameters["Param3"];

        string exePath = string.Format("{0}TechSoft CallBill.exe", targetDirectory);

        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);

        config.AppSettings.Settings["Param1"].Value = param1;

        config.AppSettings.Settings["Param2"].Value = param2;

        config.AppSettings.Settings["Param3"].Value = param3;

        config.Save();
    }
```

[image]

Please help me to sort out this error As i am not able to figure out.
Any suggestion is heartily welcomed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to load the config belongs to a different project ? or it belongs to installer class project ?

Comment: @AccessDenied Thank u very much sir.Config belongs to the installer class project.Here i am attaching the project classpath image.

Comment: @AccessDenied Please sir tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Check my answer, try that code. it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If the Config file belongs to the same project then try this, If the config file belongs to the same project then you don't have to use config file path.

```
Configuration config= ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings["Param1"].Value = param1;

config.AppSettings.Settings["Param2"].Value = param2;

config.AppSettings.Settings["Param3"].Value = param3;

//Save only the modified section of the config
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

//Refresh the appSettings section to reflect updated configurations
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(Constants.AppSettingsNode);
```

Comment: Sir what is the Constants in the Constants.AppSettingsNode because i am getting error in the Constants keyword

Comment: I tried this code but still problem persists.WindowsService1 is getting installed successfully but there is the problem in the TechSoft CallBill .Please see my project classpath image in my post

Comment: @Adi Constant value should be "appSettings"

Comment: ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(appSettings.AppSettingsNode); this line giving red mark for "appSettings"

Comment: In which project you placed the above logic ? TechSoft ? why you have two installer classes ? one in TechSoft and WindowsService1 ?

Comment: Are you sure you added TechSoft project to installer project's custom actions ?

Comment: yes sir i have added TechSoft project to installer project's custom actions and here is my customActionData=/targetdir="[TARGETDIR]\"/Param1="[EDITA1]"/Param2="[EDITA2]"/Param3="[EDITA3]"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43570/discussion-between-adi-and-accessdenied)